# Identifying outliers in correlation matrix plot

Tags: r, correlation, data-visualization, outliers

[image]

```
# Correlation plot - heatmap
cx <- colorRampPalette(viridis::mako(50))(50)
png("Heatmap_cor.matrix.png")
par(oma=c(0,0,1,0), mar=c(6,6,4,7), par(xpd=TRUE))
leg <- seq(from=0.1, to=1, length.out=10)
image(dat.cor, main="Correlation between Glioma vs Non-Tumor\n Gene Expression", col=cx, axes=F)
axis(1,at=seq(0,1,length=ncol(dat.cor)),label=dimnames(dat.cor)[[2]], cex.axis=0.9,las=2)
axis(2,at=seq(0,1,length=ncol(dat.cor)),label=dimnames(dat.cor)[[2]], cex.axis=0.9,las=2)
legend(1.1, 1.1, title="Correlation", legend=leg, fill=colorRampPalette(viridis::mako(50))(10))
dev.off()
```